# Bind AChartEngine 1.0.0 to a Mono For Android project does not works

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, achartengine

does anyone is able to bind achartengine 1.0 library to a MonoForAndroid project (rel. 4.2.7) and make this works?

I have created "Java Binding Library" project in my solution, I've copied the file  acahrtengine.jar in the folder Jars, edited the file Transforms/metadata.xml adding the following lines in order to normalize the namespace and fix a mistake:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine']" name="managedName">AChartEngine</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.chart']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Chart</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.model']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Model</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.renderer']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Renderer</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.tools']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Tools</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.util']" name="managedName">AChartEngine.Util</attr>

<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.achartengine.tools']/class[@name='Pan']/method[@name='addPanListener']" name="eventName">PanEvent</attr>
```

It complies without errors and creates the DLL but when I add the reference to my project and I try to recompile I have the following errors

```
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\PanListenerImplementor.java(8,25): javac error :  package org.achartengine.tools does not exist
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\PanListenerImplementor.java(8,25): javac error :      org.achartengine.tools.PanListener
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\PanListenerImplementor.java(8,25): javac error : 
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(8,25): javac error :  package org.achartengine.tools does not exist
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(8,25): javac error :         org.achartengine.tools.ZoomListener
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(8,25): javac error : 
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(28,49): javac error :  package org.achartengine.tools does not exist
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(28,49): javac error :    public void zoomApplied (org.achartengine.tools.ZoomEvent p0)
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(28,49): javac error : 
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(33,59): error :  package org.achartengine.tools does not exist
obj\Debug\android\src\mono\org\achartengine\tools\ZoomListenerImplementor.java(33,59): error :  private native void n_zoomApplied (org.achartengine.tools.ZoomEvent p0);
```

Any suggestion to make the AChartEngine works on Mono For Android?
Thank you

Comment: did you solve your situation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the jar file to your Monodroid project as well as referencing the binding project.

The process is described in the help docs here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar)#Add_the_Jar_to_the_Project